# Delphi How can I check the cport status?

Tags: delphi

How can I check the cport status using ComLed or label displaying Enabled/Disabled.

I've already try `If Cport1.Connected then`
But it does not satisfy me, the status keeps on telling I am connected even though I am not.

Does anyone here have a better solution?

**Note:** I use timer to check the port status.

Comment: What do you think Connected property means. Why do you think it should be false.

Comment: Sir David, maybe detecting it as false can solve the issue, It will help to compare the port status.
my question is how can I get the cport status? Thank you Sir.

Comment: My point is that surely you just don't know what the property means. Assume that the library works as designed. Now you need to understand what Connected means and what it tells you. Clearly it doesn't align with your expectations. So let me re-use my questions from my previous comment. You did not answer them. Do you have answers?

Comment: If you have sufficient wiring between the PC and the other devices, you could use DSR/DTR signals (if the device supports it). Otherwise send regularily a check message and see if you get a reply.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly,first you should find the ports that connect to your device by this code :

```
Procedure FindPorts(S:TStrings);
var
  r:TRegistry;
  i:Integer;
Begin
  R:=TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  R.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if R.OpenKey('HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM',False) then
  Begin
    R.GetValueNames(S);
    for i:=0  to S.Count-1 do
      S[i]:=R.ReadString(S[i]);
  End;
  R.CloseKey;
End;
```

Comment: This is the scenario sir Saharghodsbin, I have two cport/s to be used.

Comment: @YeojsonBarcelo, ok, and what is your problem now?

Comment: This is the scenario sir Saharghodsbin, I have 2 cport/s to be used. Scale indicator1 and Scale Indicator2.. I already connected them to my delphi project. I don't need to find ports anymore, because I already used the cport dialog which it provides a list of ports. my question is what exactly procedure can I do if I need runtime port connection status..Thanks sir.. Really apreciate..

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "port connection status"?

Comment: Sir @DavidHeffernan 

I need a label that display the status of a connected port.
the label will display "Connected" or "Disconnected".

Comment: with @saharghodsbin code you can see which port is connect. so you can put status " Connect" for that ports and the others status are "Disconnected". so, Where is your problem here?

Comment: Please define what you mean by connected and disconnected.